# Can you render a html file into a container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is going to sound like an unusual question and I don't know if it's possible but say I have a page with:

```html
<div class="container container1"></div>
<div class="container conatiner2"></div>
```

and then in CSS I have for example:

```css
.container1 {
  width: 720px;
  height: 1280px;
}

.container2 {
  width: 1080px;
  height: 1920px;
}
```

Is there any way to get these containers (`.container`) to act as individual viewports? So a user could load a separate .html file and it would load inside every `.container`?

Comment: Sounds like you're describing an [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

Comment: An entire html structure(eg with `<html>`, `<head>` tags) wouldn't be vaild inside a div or other element. Browsers would do error correction when such a structure was added to it. If needing an entire document, it would be better to use iframe. Otherwise you can inject html partials just fine just need to use the right api calls (ajax, dom manipulation)

Comment: yes for this and similar reasons (and for many other reasons) we use a framework such as Angular. It would be something like "shoot for sparrows with cannons" for this purpose but I can recommend them with a clear conscience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this any number of ways.  But the underlying technology would be to use AJAX or the Fetch Web API, pull the page you wish to embed, and place what it returns into the corresponding container.  You may need to filter out unneeded markup (stripping out the HEAD and its children, for example).  But, it's all very doable.